# Entity Framework Code first Data Annotation x Fluency API

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would know if I can use hybrid of the Data Annotation and Fluent API.
Once the Data Annotation I use to reflect on the interface/view and Fluent API I use to Database
For example:

```
public class Product
{
    [Product Identification]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(Product Name)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage= "Product Name is Required")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

}

public class ProductContext : DbContext 
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .Property(p => p.ProductId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .Property(p => p.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(100);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you test your code before asking this question?